# Mysql date and time to Unix

Tags: mysql, unix, datetime

Есть таблица packets там два столбца start_date тип данных(date) и start_time тип данных(int).
Я делаю insert в базу только дату в столбец start_date а в столбце start_time эту дату в формате Unix, можно ли чтобы в start_time было дата и время а не только дата в формат Unix, можно ли как не будь это сделать? мне нельзя столбец start_date сделать тип данных datetime.

вот от суда я отправляю данные о дате

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в start_time Unix получается только дата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой-то бессмысленный вопрос. если в столбец с unixtime записыват только дату, то там и будет только дата. если записать дату и время, то там будет - сюрприз! дата и время. Что делает колонку start_date бессмысленной. Надо сделать **одну** колонку с типом datetime и передавть в неё дату и время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать один столбец и сохранять там timestamp или datetime, например назвать его created_at.

Либо для start_time использовать тип time, а для start_date использовать тип date

Типы данных для дат в SQL
[image: Типы дат в SQL]

[**Типы данных SQL**](https://www.journaldev.com/16774/sql-data-types)

Comment: Alexandr, тоже вариант попробую спасибо